# SQL Server 2005 conditional update of a field

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the SQL below and want to update the `managerNTID` with `@managerNTID` only if the users DB record has `StopManagerOverride` value of 0, if it is set to 1 on the record then I don't want to update this field:

```
UPDATE ee
SET 
    MangerId        = CASE ee.ShopManagerOverride
                            WHEN 0 THEN @MangerId
                            ELSE ee.MangerId
                          END
    ,ManagerNTID        = CASE ee.ShopManagerOverride
                            WHEN 0 THEN @managerNTID
                            ELSE ee.ManagerNTID
                          END
    ,NTID               = @NTID
    ,FirstName          = @FirstName
    ,LastName           = @LastName
    ,FullName           = @FullName
    ,ReportingGroup     = @ReportingGroup
    ,DistinguishedName  = @DistinguishedName
    ,IsActive           = 1
    --,StopManagerOverride= 1
    ,LastUpdate         = GETDATE()
    ,UpdateBy           = @UpdateBy
FROM dbo.Employees ee
    Inner Join dbo.Employees e ON e.NTID = ee.NTID
WHERE ee.NTID = @NTID
```

Thoughts on how to make this one field in the update have an inline condition?

edit: i am almost there, just need to resolve some ambiguous columns now. my eyes are red from this already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this - if the `ShopManagerOverride` is set to 1, update it to the parameter value passed in, otherwise update it to the value it already has (I'm also assuming your field is really `ManagerId` - not `MangerId` - right??):

```
UPDATE 
    dbo.Employees
SET 
    ManagerId = @ManagerId,
    ManagerNTID = CASE e.ShopManagerOverride
                     WHEN 1 THEN @managerNTID
                     ELSE e.ManagerNTID
                  END,
    NTID = @NTID,
    FirstName = @FirstName,
    LastName = @LastName,
    FullName = @FullName,
    ReportingGroup = @ReportingGroup,
    DistinguishedName = @DistinguishedName,
    IsActive = 1,
    LastUpdate = GETDATE(),
    UpdateBy = @UpdateBy
FROM
    dbo.Employees e 
WHERE 
    e.NTID = dbo.Employees.NTID
    AND dbo.Employees.NTID = @NTID
```

Untested, straight and "free hand" from my brain - hope I got the syntax right! Try it - does it work, does it do what you're looking for??

Comment: yes, perfect but there is a syntax error im trying to fix near ON

Comment: @kacalapy: oh, right - sorry, I hope my update fixes this syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering how to do this also. I've seen Case statements but I don't know if that would work in this situation. How I've done it in the past is with copy and paste and then go like this

```
if (conditional)
Begin
Update statement with field
End
Else
Begin
update statement without field
End
```

Ok Try something like this, I'm not sure if this works but it gives you a direction to try in

```
UPDATE Employees
SET 
     MangerId           = @MangerId
    ,ManagerNTID        = @managerNTID
    ,NTID               = @NTID
    ,FirstName          = @FirstName
    ,LastName           = @LastName
    ,FullName           = @FullName
    ,ReportingGroup     = @ReportingGroup
    ,DistinguishedName  = @DistinguishedName
    ,IsActive           = 1
    ,StopManagerOverride= CASE Conditional WHEN True THEN (value to set it to)
     ELSE (pre existing value of the row) END;

    ,LastUpdate         = GETDATE()
    ,UpdateBy           = @UpdateBy
WHERE NTID = @NTID
```

Comment: that's gonna make the code look ugly and add many lines... and i asked for a solution in-line...

Comment: UPDATE Employees
 SET 
   MangerId   = @MangerId
  --,ManagerNTID  = @managerNTID
  ,ManagerNTID  = (case when (select StopManagerOverride from Employees where NTID = @NTID) = 1 then 
        (select ManagerNTID from Employees where NTID = @NTID) else 
        @managerNTID
        end)
  ,NTID    = @NTID
  ,FirstName   = @FirstName
  ,LastName   = @LastName
  ,FullName   = @FullName
  ,ReportingGroup  = @ReportingGroup
  ,DistinguishedName = @DistinguishedName
  ,IsActive   = 1
  --,StopManagerOverride= 1
  ,LastUpdate   = GETDATE()
  ,UpdateBy   = @UpdateBy
 WHERE NTID = @NTID

Comment: @kacalapy: please **do not** post long code statements in comments - it's extremely hard and annoying to read! Update your original question with any additional insights or questions you have - by editing it.

Comment: I didnt realize the text box was in the comment section.

Comment: @dko i want to leave the ManagerNTID field's value alone if StopManagerOverride is true/ 1 ELSE i want to update the ManagerNTID with @ManagerNTID if StopManagerOverride is false/ 0

Comment: yes I guess what I was aiming at there is its something like, If(conditional) ManagerNTID = newValue Else ManagerNTID = ManagerNTID. Either way you are updating the field but if you didn't want to update it, you are just updating the field to it's already existing value. It's like setting a variable equal to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Another Way is

```
 If StopManagerOverride = 0
 Begin
 Set @ManagerNTID = Select Existing Value of the row
 END
```

THen Continue with the normal update statement